# Why is there a “de” in “T'as d'autres questions ?”?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, articles, de

Why is there a “de” in “T'as d'autres questions ?”?
while we say “T'as une question ?”, “J'ai une voiture.”

In which other cases do we use “de”?

Besides, why is it “de” and not “des”?

Comment: Note that you should write "tu as …" instead of "t'as …" unless we are transcribing a conversation.

Comment: In this case, it is even better to write "As-tu d'autres questions?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally it would be *des autres* (*des* is the plural of *un/e*), but *des* changes to *de* in front of an adjective (and *de* changes to *d'* in front of a vowel).

Other examples:

*J'ai de bons amis* - I have some good friends.

*Il y a de belles filles ici* - There are some beautiful girls here.